# How to convert specific timezone to it's corresponding abbreviation in PHP?

Tags: php, timezone

My input is a timezone value (say "america/los_angeles"), and its output should be a timezone abbreviation(say "PST").

Input: "america/los_angeles" 
Output: "PST"

Input: "Asia/Kolkata" 
Output: "IST"

I know this can be done by mapping the timezone value to its corresponding abbreviation but it is time consuming.

So is there any PHP built-in function, though which I can achieve this?

Comment: Make sure you understand that the abbreviation is highly dependent on the specific date and time.  `America/Los_Angeles` is PDT in the summer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `date('T')` function to get the timezone. You'll need to set it though:

```
$input = 'america/los_angeles';
date_default_timezone_set($input);
echo date('T');
```

The reference is in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). `T` (capital) corresponds to *Timezone abbreviation*

Another variation would be to use `DateTime` classes:

```
$input = 'Asia/Kolkata';
$dt = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone($input));
echo $dt->format('T');
```

Edit: Take note, you'll also need to take into account if the input is correct or not, this throws an exception is its invalid.

You can just handle it via `try/catch`:

```
$input = 'Asia/Kolkata';
try {
    $dt = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone($input));
    echo $dt->format('T');  
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Or try to use the [listAbbreviations()](http://au.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listabbreviations.php) method of the DateTimeZone class: less intrusive (no timezone setting), but more clumsy.

Comment: @SergeyVidusov this is okay to use also, another alternative, but you'll need to search inside too

Comment: Exactly what I meant by "more clumsy".

Comment: And keep in mind since these objects initialize to the *current* date and time, the abbreviation is the one *currently* in effect.  Run this in the summer, and the first example will give `PDT` instead of `PST`, due to daylight saving time.

Answer (score 1):

From the php's [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-abbreviations-list.php):

```
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTime->setTimeZone( new DateTimeZone( 'America/Los_Angeles' ) ); 
return $dateTime->format( 'T' );
```

Will return `PST`